# Create loop arrow in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to create an arrow that goes out from the bottom of a word, and then loops around to the top of that same word. The point is to illustrate that the output of "Operations" also becomes the input of "Operations".

My initial attempt was simply to use `edge[out = -90, in = 90]`, but that doesn't make the arrow loop around the word.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) (Operations) {Operations};
    \draw [->] (Operations) edge[out = -90, in = 90] (Operations);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

In my real example, I have an arrow pointing down to "Operations" from a node above, and an arrow pointing down from "Operations" to a node below. The start and end of the loop arrow should ideally align with these two existing arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,3) (Input) {Input};
    \node at (0,1.5) (Operations) {Operations};
    \node at (0,0) (Output) {Output};
    \draw [->] (Input) -- (Operations);
    \draw [->] (Operations.center) arc (-180:180:1);
    \draw [->] (Operations) -- (Output);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Usually, even if you can produce a loop arrow by a single command it would be pretty irregular. I suggest one draw the arc by hand. Such as `\draw[->](Operations.south)arc(...);`

Comment: @Symbol1 Thanks for the suggestion. It would be great if you could provide an answer with an illustration of what you suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a very grob solution by adding a third node `\node at (1,0) (here) {};` and modifiyng the arrow's size by `looseness`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) (Operations) {Operations};
    \node at (1,0) (here) {};
    \draw [->] (Operations) to[out=-80, in=-90,looseness=2] (here)    to[out=90,in=80,looseness=2] (Operations);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

As I said in comment, with precise number

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) (Operations) {Operations};
    \draw [->] (Operations.south)arc(-160:160:1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

Another approach

```
\draw[->,shorten <=5pt,shorten >=5pt](Operations.center)arc(-180:180:1);
```

[image]

---

---

Third approach

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,3) (Input) {Input};
    \node at (0,1.5) (Operations) {Operations};
    \node at (0,0) (Output) {Output};
    \draw [->] (Input) -- (Operations);
    \draw [->] (Operations) -- (Output);
    \draw[->](Operations.south)arc(-180:0:1)coordinate(X)
             (Operations.north)+(2,0)--(X)
             (Operations.north)+(2,0)arc(0:180:1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So there is no way to tell it that it should end at `Operations.north`?

Comment: If you are willing to break this path into two paths, yes. But either it is not going to be a perfect arc, or you need to do some tedious  calculation to determine what `160` should be replaced by. (Wait... I have a good idea.)

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because I have another straight arrow pointing down to `Operations` (for what provides the initial input to "Operations"), and I would like the arrow of this loop to end up exactly where that straight arrow ends up.

Comment: Please see the updated question.

Comment: @Sverre I add the third approach